# How do I put an interstitial ad every time the app is opened (kotlin)

Tags: kotlin, admob, interstitial

I want an interstitial ad to be loaded with admob every time my app is opened, how do I do it? i am working with kotlin

Answer (score 3):

You should not place interstitial ads on app load, that would be a [disallowed interstitial implementation](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201362):

> Do not place interstitial ads on app load and when exiting apps as interstitials should only be placed in between pages of app content.

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed start loading your AdMob ads upon app launch, however when it comes to interstitials, you shouldn't show them on app opening. AdMob has recently introduced a new ad format specifically designed for such cases: **[App Open Ad](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/app-open)**. It is exactly what you're looking for.